# How do I make mouse movement gradual with pydirectinput

Tags: python, mouse

I'm working on a project that requires me to be able to move the mouse in a video game. I tried pyautogui, but that doesn't work for games, so pydirectinput is the next best thing.

I am able to get the mouse cursor to move from point A to point B, however instead of moving there over a set period of time, it seems to just teleport there instead, and that can be really jarring. Is there a way to make pydirectinput gradually move to where it needs to go instead of teleporting the mouse to a set of coordinates?

I am currently using the code shown below for my mouse movement. Note that I did try with and without the duration and relative declarations.

```
def move_mouse(move, direction, dur):
    if direction == 'N':  # up
        mouse.moveRel(0, -move, duration=dur, relative=True)
    elif direction == 'S':  # down
        mouse.moveRel(0, move, duration=dur, relative=True)
    elif direction == 'W':  # left
        mouse.moveRel(-move, 0, duration=dur, relative=True)
    elif direction == 'E':  # right
        mouse.moveRel(move, 0, duration=dur, relative=True)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
import pydirectinput
import time

# Define the target coordinates (x, y) where you want the cursor to move
target_x, target_y = 500, 500

# Get the current mouse position
current_x, current_y = pydirectinput.position()

# Calculate the step size for each movement
step_x = (target_x - current_x) / 50  # You can adjust the number of steps
step_y = (target_y - current_y) / 50

# Perform a series of small mouse movements to reach the target location
for _ in range(50):  # 50 steps in this example, you can adjust as needed
    current_x += step_x
    current_y += step_y
    pydirectinput.moveTo(int(current_x), int(current_y))
    time.sleep(0.05)  # Adjust the sleep time as needed for the desired speed

# Ensure the cursor reaches the exact target location
pydirectinput.moveTo(target_x, target_y)
```

In this code:

1. You specify the target coordinates (target_x and target_y) where you want the mouse cursor to move.
2. You calculate the step size for each movement based on the number of steps (50 in this example).
3. Using a loop, you gradually move the mouse cursor in small steps toward the target location.
4. You use time.sleep to introduce a delay between each step to control the speed of the cursor movement.
5. Finally, you ensure the cursor reaches the exact target location.

You can adjust the number of steps and sleep time to control the speed and smoothness of the cursor movement according to your needs.

Comment: Thanks for that! Taking a look at the difference between pyautogui and pydirectinput really helped on this one. It looks like auto implemented a way to deal with duration, while direct will take duration in but not do anything with it. I ended up copying the code from auto and implementing it in my own code.

The only issue with this is that now the duration ends up being 3x the duration due to the time it takes for the code to be resolved, so I am now trying to resolve that